# saving data in iphone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I am trying to download an image and audio file from the url.. i want to save the downloaded files in specific path is it possible..

please suggest me...

thanks...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xcode/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

save the files in the documents directory of your app.

```
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myfile.mp3"];
BOOL success = [myMp3Data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *filePath2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg", documentsDirectory, fileName]; 
NSData* imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(drawImage.image, 1.0); 
[imageData writeToFile:filePath2 atomically:NO];
```